# Why can't activate emmet.vim?

Tags: vim, debian, emmet

emmet.vim had been installed via vundle.

```
$ cd ~/.vim/bundle    
$ git clone git@github.com:mattn/emmet-vim.git

ls  .vim/bundle/emmet-vim
autoload  emmet.vim.vimup  plugin      TODO      unittest.vim
doc       Makefile         README.mkd  TUTORIAL
```

To reboot and edite test.html file.

```
cd /tmp
vim  test.html
```

To do as manual say:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981

```
Type abbreviation
 +-------------------------------------
 | html:5_
 +-------------------------------------
"_" is a cursor position. and type "<c-y>," (Ctrl + y and Comma)
```

It is no use to input **html5 and ctrl+y+,** this way.

[image]

It is no use to input **html5 and ctrl+y+,** this way too.

[image]

Comment: 1. Did you press `<C-y>` followed immediately by `,`? 2. The installation method you describe is not "install via vundle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case that emmet is not installed correctly or available.

To make sure if emmet is available, run `:scriptnames` and see if emmet is there

If not install it correctly from https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim

To use emmet, you have to follow the first method you mentioned. ie typing in html5 in editing space itself and do <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> followed by <kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: :scriptnames  ,no emmet there.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: So you'll just have to install it correctly. I use vundle for plugin management. Do you have vundle installed?

Answer (score 0):

To install it with pathogen

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim.git
```

Comment: if you have vundle installed, it might be best to use vundle to install emmet. Makes things like updating easy